# CoreData takes too long to save a Dictionary

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm saving a dictionary with 1000 items and it takes around 3/4 seconds to do it. Which seems to me like a really long time. This happens successfully when I call `addEmojisDictionary`. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var emojisEntities: [EmojiEntity] = []
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR LOADING CORE DATA. \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func addEmojisDictionary(_ emojisDictionary: [String: String]) {
        print("addEmojis - start")
        emojisDictionary.values.forEach { value in
            let newEmoji = EmojiEntity(context: self.container.viewContext)
            newEmoji.urlString = value
            self.saveData()
        }
        print("addEmojis - end")
    }
    
    private func saveData() {
        do {
            if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
                try container.viewContext.save()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call save() after each insert, do it at the end or at an interval like after every 100 inserts

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides saving only once outside of the forEach loop might already greatly improve performance, there is still something to keep in mind: The viewContext is being written to on the main thread. This might not be a problem for many use-cases, but depending on the size of the objects you import data from, this can still cause a choppy UI.

So, for the sake of best practices, I recommend you to use:

1. A background context that you execute the save on and merge back changes to the viewContext.
2. NSBatchInsertRequest (Check out Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest)